# Cheap base for job hunting in the US after relocation

Tags: usa, job-hunting, relocation, financial

I'm considering relocating to the US before finding a job there [in order to improve the chances of getting one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/35244/25369) (yes, I am able to do that legally). However, this will of course cost a huge amount of money; How/where can I establish a low-cost "base of operations" for my search? — I need a permanent address (to open a bank account, get a driving license, etc.) but don't have an income to show to potential landlords. I have no relatives or close friends in well-connected places who could host me in such a manner, and I don't want to be stuck in some backwater without a car, as I'll never get a job that way.

Comment: I would think that you could open a bank account in an online US bank from where ever you are now. As for finding a job, you do not mention what kind of work you are looking for or have the credentials (university degree or other) for. That would certainly make a difference in location. Finally I suggest that you create a list of possible locations based on several criteria: good public transit, good selection of jobs in the industrial or vocational area you are interested. There are a number of job search web sites that can help you with the job area. Good luck.

Comment: @RichardChambers your information is patently false: it is generally not possible to open a bank account without a physical address (I have not checked with every minor bank out of thousands, so I cannot write "impossible"); please remove your comment in order to avoid misleading others.

Comment: I said nothing about opening a bank account without a physical address. However there are services for establishing a physical address with mail forwarding if that is needed. How do digital nomads do it? https://medium.com/nomad-gate/the-world-s-best-bank-accounts-for-international-travelers-and-nomads-3257e6839cff